# NHibernate Select Max value with filter

Tags: nhibernate, filter, max

I am trying to get the max value from a table, doing something like this:

```
        SELECT max(re.Sequence) FROM MyTable re WHERE re.ItemId = :itemId
```

So i can get for each itemId the maximum value for the column Sequence.

Tried with createQuery but didn´t worked:

```
        string hql = @"SELECT new Int32(max(re.Sequence) FROM MyTable re WHERE re.Item.Id = :itemId";
        List<Int32> lista =  session
            .CreateQuery(hql)
            .SetParameter("itemId", idItem)
            .List<Int32>()
            .ToList();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the criteria syntax:

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<MyTable>();
criteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("ItemId", itemId));
criteria.SetProjection(Projections.Max("Sequence"));
var max = criteria.UniqueResult<int>();
```

Using the query over syntax:

```
var max = session.QueryOver<MyTable>().Where(x => x.ItemId.Equals(itemId)).Select(
                Projections.Max<MyTable>(x => x.Sequence)).SingleOrDefault<int>();
```

Comment: Perfect, this works, I just corrected the 2nd line to "Restrictions" and 3rd line to "SetProjection". Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: I tried something like this, but UniqueResult returns NonUniqueResultException (NHibernate 3.3).
    var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<MyTable>();
    criteria.SetProjection(Projections.Max("PropertyWithDateTime"));
    var max = criteria.UniqueResult<DateTime>();